# New to JSF need help with generating Dynamic Content

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

HI,

I'm new to JSF and am trying to use the examples from the book "Begining JSF 2APIs and JBoss Seam" by kent Ka lok Tong. I followed all the instructions but when I run the project from Eclipse the Dynamic Content is not displayed. running it from IE or mozilla firefox gives the same result (static content is displayed but not the dynamic) 
I'm using Eclipse Galelio 3.5.2 and JBoss 5.0.0.CR2

The following are the files I created:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>hello11</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSF</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSF</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

**hello11.xhtml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

Hello static.

<br/>

Hello <h:outputText value="John"></h:outputText>

</body>
```

web.xml and faces-config.xml are under /WEB-INF and the hello11.xhtml is under the /WebContent

I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the configuration...

Thanks.

Comment: in your code doesnt look like you have any dynamic content ... all in your hello11.xhtml is static. so i'd say everything is ok

Comment: @Diogo: there's a `<h:outputText/>`. Do you know JSF anyway?

Comment: @BalusC: i thought <h:outputText value="John"/> would output "John". theres not really much about dynamic in that. i thought dynamic would mean some bean doing some stuff server side and outputing whatever variables. sorry about that.

Comment: @Diogo: It won't print that if `FacesServlet` hasn't done its job. It's namely not part of static HTML. I'd say, open up a basic JSF tutorial/book and read the 1st chapter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the request URL (the one in browser address bar) matches the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`. It's namely the one responsible for doing all the JSF works. Assuming that you're running the server on localhost on port 8080 and that the project name is "playground", then the URL should be

http://localhost:8080/playground/faces/hello.xhtml

and thus *not*

http://localhost:8080/playground/hello.xhtml

Alternatively, you can also change the `url-pattern` to `*.xhtml` so that you don't need to do this. The only disadvantage would be that you cannot open a "plain vanilla" XHTML file without that the `FacesServlet` kicks in. But I don't think that wou would ever need that.

---

**Update**: As Arjan mentions, JSF 2.0 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 container, but JBoss 5.0.0 CR2 is a Servlet 2.4 container. You have 2 options: downgrade to JSF 1.2 or upgrade servletcontainer to a Servlet 2.5 compatible one.

Comment: is it `/faces/hello.xhtml`, or `/faces/hello` ? (I've never mapped my faces servlet to this type of URL)

Answer (score 2):

What is the request URL that you use to access this page?

Since you are using prefix mapping, you should include that in your request. E.g.

`http://localhost:8080/faces/hello11.xhtml`

Then the next problem is that you may think you're using Facelets and JSF 2.0, but JBoss 5.0.0.CR2 doesn't have support for this out of the box. By default it comes with JSF 1.2 and JSP only.

If you want JSF 2.0 on JBoss AS 5, you need to install and configure this explicitly. Have you done this?

If you haven't, then for the time being you can use JSP instead (rename your file to .jsp and use jsp:root. You also need to use f:view in this case:

```
<jsp:root version="2.0"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
>
    <f:view>
            put JSF stuff here
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Finally, why are you using JBoss 5.0.0.CR2? This makes very little sense. If you want or need to use Java EE 5, then use the latest released version which is JBoss AS 5.1.

In only a few days JBoss AS 6 will be released, which is a much better version to start with. Namely, this one does come with JSF 2.0 (and thus Facelets) support out of the box. You could use JBoss AS 6 CR1 in the mean time.

Comment: Facelets already ships with JSF 2.0 (OP is using JSF 2.0 as per faces-config declaration and question tags), but with JBoss there you've got a point. JSF 2.0 requires a servlet 2.5 container and JBoss 5.0.0 isn't, it supports at highest servlet 2.4.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. But my hunch was that the OP thinks he's using Facelets (and JSF 2.0) but in reality isn't. My guess is that the OP has just copied the examples from that JSF2 tutorial and that JBoss 5.0 starts up fine with a faces-config that's for a higher version (2.0 thus) than JBoss 5 bundles. I'll update my answer to clarify this.

Comment: yes, I followed the instructions form the book exactly as they are. my question is what would be the best combination of Eclipse/JBoss/Java EE versions to use if I were to start from scratch? I'm assuming the book is using the versions that were abvailable at the time it was written but there are newer verisons now.Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), JBoss AS 6, Java EE 6 (JSF 2.0 & Facelets). If the book explains how to use JSF 2.0 & Facelets with JBoss 5, it probably also has explained somewhere that this doesn't work out of the box. You need to download a JSF 2.0 implementation and include this in your .war. This is **not** needed when you use JBoss AS 6, since it bundles JSF 2.0 out of the box.

Comment: p.s. JBoss AS 6 has been released a few days early. It's available now ;)

Comment: Thanks, Eclipse 3.6, Java EE 6, and JBoss AS 5.1 worked. I 'm still wondering how the book got it to work with the older versions without any further explanations.